Document Window selection behavior
I discovered the Document window which allows me to quickly jump to Methods in my C# files.  However, I noticed one scenario where clicking a method in the Document Window does nothing on the screen except change the current Line Number.  This occurs if the method signature is already on the screen (text editor).  When this happens I have to manually find the method on the screen. At a minimum I would like to make the Current Line # more prominent.  How can I make the Current Line # in the Left Gutter more prominent.  Event better, how can I make the Document Window Highlight the Method Signature and center on it everytime?
Thank you


What is the version of your visual studio? Does this issue occur in a specific project or all types of projects? Please try to create a new project(e.g: console app c#) to do a test and  narrow down this issue. By the way, try to  repair your VS from VS Installer to see if the issue persists.

My current Version is 17.11.4.  It works identically in a Console C# project.  I was excited about this feature.   I wish it would center the selected method in the middle of the screen.  I don't fully understand what VS developers were intending with this feature or it seems to be incomplete.

I did a quick test on 17.11.4 and found when i clicked the method in Documnet window, it will change the current Line Number and highlight the selected method in  the "middle"(You can see the location at a glance) of the screen. Please see my  Test result

That's exactly what I want.  It's not behaving that way for me Dou.  It's just changing the Line number.  Not even positioning the Method in the middle of the screen.  I am using 17.11.4.  It must be a setting or I might need to repair my VS.

I would have posted a video but not sure how Dou.

Looks like you might try to repair your VS or update to the latest version 17.11.5 to see if the issue occurs. Stack Overflow does not support uploading videos directly, you can embed videos from other platforms like YouTube  by including the video link in your post.

Dou, my friend just did a fresh install of VS Community and the Document Outline works for him as shown in your video.   I Just downloaded the latest VS version 17.11.5, and my Document Outline still doesn't work correctly.
I currently have the following extensions installed but I disabled them and the problem still occurs.
CleanBinandObj and HideQuickActionsIcon.
I think it's a setting somewhere.  What are your thoughts Dou?  I could re-install VS but I would really like to import my settings file and if it is indeed a setting I am back to the original problem if I import.

In this case, i guess some third-party extensions have changed a setting somewhere .I suggest you try to export and reset settings. If the issue disappear after resetting settings, this is the root cause. Then import your settings file to verify it to see if the issue reoccurs. If it's convenient for you, you can consider uninstall visual studio via InstallCleanup.exe and then do a refresh  install.

Dou, I reset the settings and Document Window works as expected, hence, it's a setting issue not a VS issue.  When I re-import my original settings file, the issue re-occurs.  The Question now is what is the setting that is causing Document Window to misbehave?


I noticed one scenario where clicking a method in the Document Window does nothing on the screen except change the current Line Number.

For this issue, glad to hear that the Document Window behaves well after resetting visual studio settings. Looks like some third-party extensions you installed/your customized settings and Document Window conflict.

The Question now is what is the setting that is causing Document Window to misbehave?

I suggest you compare the two files: your original settings file and Visual Studio default settings file.
In Solution Explorer, select two files (use Ctrl-click to select), you can right-click and choose Compare Selected to open the diff view with just those two files.
Note: it may be time consuming.
Docs Referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/compare-with?view=vs-2022

Dou, when I reset my settings the Document Window still does not center the editor window on the method signature if it is currently visible at the bottom.  It only centers when the method signature is not visible in the editor.  Does yours behave that way?  See original Screenshot Item 3)

Yes, it behaves that way in my VS as you described above. Not sure if is by-design.  I would suggest you to support this issue at VS Community to confirm with MS  product group if it's a product issue or by-design.

Thank you for confirming Dou.  If this is the case the only current benefit I would get is the Highlighting of the Method Name.  Since I made the Current Line Number more salient I pretty much have the same functionality already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79147905/visual-studio-current-line-font-size-and-color

Dou, the reason the method name did not Highlight is because I had
Highlight references to symbol under cursor Deselected.  Thanks for all your help Dou!

Dou, can you Upvote this feature please.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Text-Editor-does-not-Center-when-I-selec/10796950
