Visual Studio Current Line # Font Size and Color
I would like to change the Font and Color of the Current Line #.  I couldn't find this attribute in the Settings.


Thank you for your assistance with this question. Please direct me to the correct setting in VS. I expect to be able to change the Font and Color of the Current Line #.

Please tag the specific version of VS that you're using.

You want the Line Number (Current) setting:

Display items lists a few of the more popular settings first with the remaining settings sorted alphabetically.
